# Finding longest string in an array (even if it's an array of numbers)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

When I run this:

```
var array= [123, ["hello", 67, 888888], "try", {key: "key", value: "this is the longest String"}]
longestString(array);

correct answer:
>>>"this is the longest String" 

current answer:
>>>"try"
```

How can I update this function to pass the above test and return the correct answer?

below is the longestString() function:

```
function longestString(array) {
    // return the longest string in the array
    var longest = 0;
    var longestString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length > longest && typeof array[i] =="string") {
        longest = array[i].length;
        longestString = array[i];
        }
    }
    return longestString;
}
```

Comment: because the nested array length is longer (5) than the string `'tiny'` (4)

Comment: Your requirements actually aren’t clear. Why should the array be shorter than `"tiny"`? Do you want to compare every Array element, no matter how nested it is? What about objects with key-value pairs or ES6 Symbols? How should these cases be handled?

Comment: well the array isn't a string it's an array... it asks for the longest string. However, I would like to update this to also check all strings within nested arrays and or nested objects as well. Would you have a solution to check for these conditions as well? When I run this: longestString([123, ["hello", 67, 888888], "try", {key: "key", value: "this is the longest String"}]) The answer should be "this is the longest String" but it says "try" is the longest string..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/bn-BD/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check that data is string or not

like this

```
function longestString(array) {
    // return the longest string in the array
    var longest = 0;
    var longestString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length > longest && typeof array[i] ==="string") {
        longest = array[i].length;
        longestString = array[i];
        }
    }
    return longestString;
}
```

**EDIT**

for strings within nested arrays/ objects?

Try like this

```
function longestString(array) {
    // return the longest string in the array
    var longest = 0;
    var longestString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array[i]) === '[object Array]') {
            array[i].forEach(function (it) {
                if (it.length > longest) {
                    longest = it.length;
                    longestString = it;
                }
            })
        } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array[i]) === '[object Object]') {
            for (var j in array[i]) {
                if (array[i][j].length > longest) {
                    longest = array[i][j].length;
                    longestString = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        } else if (typeof array[i] == "string" && array[i].length > longest) {
            longest = array[i].length;
            longestString = array[i];
        }
    }
    return longestString;
}

console.log(longestString([123, ["hello", 67, 888888], "try", {
    key: "key",
    value: "this is the longest String"
}]));
```

Comment: Thanks Anik! This worked after I changed "===" to "=="

Comment: `===` is strict checking it don't convert during checking and `==` this use conversion during checking. as typeof always return string `===` or `==` shouldn't be the problem. By the way you are welcome :)

Comment: Would you know how to update the function so that it would consider to look at strings within nested arrays/ objects? When I run this: longestString([123, ["hello", 67, 888888], "try", {key: "key", value: "this is the longest String"}]) The answer should be "this is the longest String" but it says "try" is the longest string..

Comment: Awesome ANIK! You are the best :)